# Lua/LOVE indexing problems

Tags: arrays, indexing, lua, love2d

I'm getting a very irritating error whenever I do *anything* like this with arrays. I have code that sets up the array in the love.load() function:

```
function iceToolsInit()
    objectArray = {} --for object handling
    objectArrayLocation = 0
end
```

and then code that allows for the creation of an object. It basically grabs all of the info about said object and plugs it into an array.

```
function createObject(x, y, renderimage) --used in the load function
    --objectArray is set up in the init function
    objectArrayLocation = objectArrayLocation + 1
    objectArray[objectArrayLocation] = {}
    objectArray[objectArrayLocation]["X"] = x
    objectArray[objectArrayLocation]["Y"] = y
    objectArray[objectArrayLocation]["renderimage"] = 
        love.graphics.newImage(renderimage)
end
```

After this, an update function reads through the objectArray and renders the images accordingly:

```
function refreshObjects() --made for the update function
    arrayLength = #objectArray
    arraySearch = 0
    while arraySearch <= arrayLength do
        arraySearch = arraySearch + 1
        renderX = objectArray[arraySearch]["X"]
        renderY = objectArray[arraySearch]["Y"]
        renderimage = objectArray[arraySearch]["renderimage"]
        if movingLeft == true then --rotation for rightfacing images
            renderRotation = 120
        else
            renderRotation = 0
        end
        love.graphics.draw(renderimage, renderX, renderY, renderRotation)
    end
end
```

I of course clipped some unneeded code (just extra parameters in the array such as width and height) but you get the gist. When I set up this code to make one object and render it, I get this error:

```
attempt to index '?' (a nil value)
```

the line it points to is this line:

```
renderX = objectArray[arraySearch]["X"]
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here, and how I could prevent it in the future? I really need help with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's off-by-one error:

```
arraySearch = 0
while arraySearch <= arrayLength do
    arraySearch = arraySearch + 1
```

You run through the loop `arrayLength+1` number of times, going through indexes `1..arrayLength+1`. You want to go through the loop only `arrayLength` number of times with indexes `1..arrayLength`. The solution is to change the condition to `arraySearch < arrayLength`.

Another (more Lua-ly way) is to write this as:

```
for arraySearch = 1, #objectArray do
```

Even more Lua-ly way is to use `ipairs` and `table.field` reference instead of (`table["field"]`):

```
function refreshObjects()
  for _, el in ipairs(objectArray) do
    love.graphics.draw(el.renderimage, el.X, el.Y, movingLeft and 120 or 0)
  end
end
```

`objectArray` and `movingLeft` should probably be passed as parameters...